# Need help with a LINQ ArgumentOutOfRangeException in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Hoping this is a nice softball of a question for a friday but I have the following line of code:

```
//System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException generated if there is no matching data
currentAnswers = new CurrentAnswersCollection()
    .Where("PARTICIPANT_ID", 10000).Load()[0];
```

CurrentAnswersCollection is a strongly-typed collection populated by a view going back to my database.
The problem of course is that if there is not a corresponding PARTICIPANT_ID = 10000 I get the error message.

Is there a better way to write this so that I wouldn't get the error message at all?
I just dont know enough about LINQ syntax to know if I can test for the existance first?

thanks.

Comment: Investigate stack trace. It usually gives very precise place of error.

Comment: If you are using Dynamic LINQ you might try changing your `.Where` expression to `.Where("PARTICIPANT_ID=@p0", 10000)`.  But to answer the question about the ArgumentOutOfRangeException, see David M's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
currentAnswers = new CurrentAnswersCollection()
    .Where("PARTICIPANT_ID", 10000).Load()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

It'll return null if there is no first element.

But you may need to fix your code (replicated here) first - the `.Where` syntax looks dodgy.

Comment: Did you actually try to run this code? It shouldn't even compile. .Where needs a lambda. Here's the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx

Comment: Very true - up to the .FirstOrDefault, this was just the OP's code returned to him.

Comment: @Cylon Cat, he could be using Dynamic LINQ library. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: It's not necessarily true that FirstOrDefault will return null for an empty Enumeration.  If the Enumeration contains say int it will return 0.  As it name suggests it returns the default if empty which is null for reference types.

Comment: True, I assumed from the naming that this was a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

The ArgumentOutOfRangeException is occurring when you try to use the indexer to get the first item from the (empty) list.  Using the FirstOrDefault() extension method is a convenient way to return the first element of a collection, if there is one, otherwise to return null.

```
currentAnswers = new CurrentAnswersCollection().Where("PARTICIPANT_ID", 10000)
                                               .Load()
                                               .FirstOrDefault();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need a lambda expression in .Where.

```
currentAnswers = new CurrentAnswersCollection()
    .Where(c => c.PARTICIPANT_ID == 10000).Load().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: His code seems to work, except when there are no items returned. "Lambda" is not the problem, "[0]" is.

Comment: The question had two parts, the lack of == and the exception. Cylon Cat answered the == part.

Comment: @ANeves, "seems to work"? Every overload of IEnumerable .Where() requires a delegate. There's no way that .Where can work when the first parameter is a string.

Comment: Guys, he could be very well using Dynamic LINQ.  It doesn't have to use lambda expressions http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: @Cylon Cat, had this been part of this problem he would have a compiler error and not a runtime exception.

Comment: @Cylon Cat, I thought *exactly* what you thought. But then reading his question and explanation of the problem it seems like it was working, just not when returning 0 items... So I shrugged and disregarded the apparent syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var answers = new CurrenAnswersCollection().Where("PARTICIPANT_ID", 10000);
if(answers.Count() >= 1) currentAnswers = answers.Load()[0];
```

or something similar.